# Display guitar chords on a circuit display

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, display, guitar, music-notation

I'm doing a project which needs to display guitar chord patterns on a display using IoT. which board(Arduino or raspberry) and display is more suitable?

Comment: Where does your project get the chord from and how do you want to display it? If it's about listening to a guitar and automatically display the recognized chord: good luck, and don't start out with an Arduino.

Comment: Circuit use a mic to detect chords played by someone and display the player whether the payed guitar is correct or wrong using correlation. which display is more suitable when showing guitar chord patterns? like this https://truefire.com/inc/img/chord-charts/10-beginner-guitar-chords.jpg

Comment: Hardware recommendations are off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Raspberry is much more powerful than Arduino, but Arduino is cheaper and requires much less energy. Also, your network connectivity requirements are unclear, but in general, the Arduino is much limited compared to the Raspberry, in terms of connectivity.

If this is a one-off project, the additional cost is acceptable, and you have no power constraints, the easiest would probably be to use the Raspberry.